# Upload Images in Tiny Mce editor + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, tinymce

I am using the Tiny Mce editor for adding the content from back end. I need to add images inside the content, but I have added the image plugin in the plugin list but its not showing me the browse option and also not showing the images inside the content, its showing the blank images, why its happening I am not able to understand. Should I need a File manager for uploading images or how could I achieve this?

```
tinyMCE.init
    mode: "exact"
    elements: elementId
    height: 500
    content_css : "/assets/admin/tinymce_title.css",
    fontsize_formats: "12pt 14pt 18pt"
    theme: "modern"
    plugins: ["lists link image charmap preview hr pagebreak", "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars fullscreen", "insertdatetime nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality", "paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"]
    image_advtab: true,

    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | unlink link image"
    toolbar2: "preview | forecolor backcolor"
```

This my code for tiny mce. I am using `gem 'tinymce-rails', '4.1.6'`

Answer (score 1):

Try [tinymce-rails-imageupload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload) gem, it seems it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I used it and its resolved my problem... thanks for answer